# Image in a div affects rows in table

Tags: html, css

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Left Text
        <div style='text-align:right;float:right;'>
            <img src='./close.png' height='40px' />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        This text gets bumped down due to imag
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hey guys...

My issue is I have a table with a lot of rows... On one row I need to align an image to the right, although the images height pushes down the next row and causes a lot of white space.

Is it possible to have the next row not be affected by the div and image?

Greg

Comment: Give the tr ot td a position of relative, give the img a position of absolute, place the image using offset properties such as top: 5px; left: 10px; It will be than be taken out of the normal flow of the document and no white space will occour!

Comment: ah ha. I think that might be the solution.

Comment: @Greg: Use @ with the name, so people can know you have commented as it shows up in the inbox. Do you want me to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

**OOPS... Just realized that I forgot about the table after posting sorry, the solution is really only going to work properly for divs**

I see 3 potential solutions depending on how you want content displayed. All using CSS.

1: Manipulate the div with a height and specify how you want the overflow to be handled

```
.mydiv1{
     height:100px;
     overflow:hidden; //optionally you can specify visible so it overflows and remains completely visible depending on your content
}
```

2: specify an image size that will be contained within the div and not affect the rest of the page

```
img.myimg {
     height:90px;
     width:90px;
}
```

3: place the image into the div as a background image

```
.mydiv1 {
     background-image:url('myimage.png');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Or you can use a combination depending on what you're wanting to do.

Note: I have used classes and not IDs assuming that you may use the code in more than 1 div, just specify the class name in the `class` property for the element

Comment: Thanks for the advice anyway. I noticed that the issue in the table cause problems. Maybe i'll just have to remove the table completely.

Comment: No problem mate, tables typically are not best practice any longer but it does depend on your usage, you need to use a solution that is right for you. Personally I have been using divs for a few years - actually about 4 now as preference, I have a couple of sites that use very different methods of creating this row-column-like structure, just play and see what is right for your site. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Specify a `height` and `width` for the image in the `img` tag. This way you will be able to restrict the height and width of the image.

Comment: But the image must be atleast 40px height... that would effect normal text

Comment: @Greg: You should always specify a `height` and `width` for an image. Now, if the image must be at least 40px, then you need to allocate it that much space. That's what the browser is doing, by pushing down the next row.

Comment: The height and width does not really effect my question I dont think. But thanks for letting me know that. Im trying to figure out a way to have a div in a row that would not effect the next row.

Comment: @Greg: Why do you need that `div` around the image? If you need to float the image, then do it by applying `float: right` style directly to the `img` tag.

Comment: That would work as well... I did the div because I did not know what content I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this in two ways that I can think of without cutting the image at the new row.

1. Set the div to have height 1px. Then the image will expand but since the parent container is only 1px it will not affect the row height. (If the image has float)
2. Position absolute on the picture and position relative on the div.

Anyway I wouldnt recomend any of it since the image wont push away the text (or a new image) on the second row. So depending on your content i would probably loose the table if that is possible.